# Interactive Javascript Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a javascript interactive menu or an image map, and when you press down, highlight, and press enter on four things on the map/menu, hidden messages should pop up! But, I am really bad with javascript and could use some help.

I've coded this little menu-thingy with HTML.

https://e33440.neocities.org/Restaurant.html
and that's what I would like to use as a base, but I don't really know where to add javascript. I've already planned that I wanted "Eggs Benedict" or "Creamy Chicken Soup" to be the things that would have hidden messages- like ingredients or potential allergens. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hello there! You can use build-in stackoverflow feature `code snippet`, instead of additional links. And please be more clearly and formatted in your questions.

Comment: Add JavaScript by adding the following tag to your html `<script src="restaurant.js"></script>` then write code in the file indicated by the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "pop-up" box are you thinking of? Would it be one you could style with CSS yourself, or more of like a normal alert box?